# Custom emoji in discord.py (on_reaction_add) not working

Tags: bots, discord.py, emoji

I'm sorry for my english, i'm french :P

I'm doing a discord bot in python (i'm a beginner in python) and i'm doing it step by step. Right now, I want the bot react when user click on an emoji. I used 3 custom emojii, it's not working :(

For the test, i tried with a :slight_smile: and it works perfectly. I don't know if i'm doing it wrong, or if i can't do that with  custom emojii...

Can you help me finding what's going wrong on my code? :)

```
    @bot.command(name="mm",help="permet de créer une invit mm+ avec !mm clé niveau heure. Exemple: !mm Boralus +14 21h00")
async def mm(ctx, arg, arg2, arg3):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Inscription pour {} en {} vers {}" .format(arg, arg2, arg3), description="Composition du groupe") #,color=Hex code
    embed.add_field(name="Tank", value="<:tank:761252435720667157>tank\n", inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name="Heal", value="<:heal:761252937548169246>heal\n", inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name="Dps1", value="<:dps:761252937066217512>dps1\n", inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name="Dps2", value="<:dps:761252937066217512>dps2\n", inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name="Dps3", value="<:dps:761252937066217512>dps3\n", inline = False)
# On ajoute les emojis
    sent = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    emojis=['<:tank:761252435720667157>', '<:heal:761252937548169246>', '<:dps:761252937066217512>', '' ]
    for emoji in emojis:
        await sent.add_reaction(emoji)
# On réagit aux emoji
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    message = reaction.message
    emoji = reaction.emoji
    tank = "<:tank:761252435720667157>"
    heal = "<:heal:761252937548169246>"
    dps = "<:dps:761252937066217512>"
    test = ""
    if user.bot:
        return

    if emoji == tank:
        print ("testtank")
    elif emoji == heal:
        print ("testheal")
    elif emoji == dps:
        print ("testdps")
    elif emoji == test:
        print ("smiley")
    else:
        return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should let the bot get the corresponding emote object. That way you're able to compare the reaction emote and your tank, heal, dps, etc emotes with each other. Here is my solution which also includes the reaction check inside the command. If you have any follow up questions, feel free to ask. Im happy to help.

```
@bot.command()
async def mm(ctx, arg, arg2, arg3):
      embed = discord.Embed(title="Inscription pour {} en {} vers {}" .format(arg, arg2, arg3), description="Composition du groupe") #,color=Hex code
      embed.add_field(name="tank", value="<:cosmic_ok:705879274464477375>\n", inline = False) #different emotes because i didnt have yours. just switch them out
      embed.add_field(name="heal", value="<:smol:672722017719549983>\n", inline = False)
      embed.add_field(name="dps", value="<:shumbe:671080877782204444>\n", inline = False)

      sent = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
      emojis=['<:cosmic_ok:705879274464477375>', '<:smol:672722017719549983>', '<:shumbe:671080877782204444>']
      for emoji in emojis:
            await sent.add_reaction(emoji)

      tank = bot.get_emoji(705879274464477375) #returns an emoji object. the emote id is the numbers when you type \:emotehere: on discord and send the message
      heal = bot.get_emoji(672722017719549983)
      dps = bot.get_emoji(671080877782204444)

      def check(reaction, user): #checks if the reaction was on the embed sent by the bot and if the person who reacted is the one who invoked the command. can be changed to whatever you like
            return reaction.message.id == sent.id and user == ctx.author

       while True:
            try: # tries to execute code after this. the except keyword executes code when an error was raised during this.
                 reaction, _ = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=20.0, check=check) # the bot waits for a reaction to happen. when no reaction was added or passed the check in 20 seconds, asyncio.TimeoutError is raised.

                 if reaction.emoji == tank: # checks if the reaction emote equals the tank emote
                       print('tank')

                 if reaction.emoji == heal:
                      print('heal')
        
                 if reaction.emoji == dps:
                      print('dps')
            except asyncio.TimeoutError: # exits the loop when no reaction was added or passed the check in 20 seconds. you can also just write pass here.
                 break
```

Comment: Thank you :) it's even more than what i asked :D will try to edit the field now^^

when someone press the "tank" emoji - edit tank field with the @username :D

Answer (score 0):

In custom emojis, you should get their ID's with doing `\'emoji'` in your guild's chat. As I can see, you get the ID's, but you forgot adding `<>` at the beginning and the end.

Instead of

```
tank = ":tank:761252435720667157"
heal = ":heal:761252937548169246"
dps = ":dps:761252937066217512"
```

You should use

```
tank = "<:tank:761252435720667157>"
heal = "<:heal:761252937548169246>"
dps = "<:dps:761252937066217512>"
```

And also instead of

```
emojis=[':tank:761252435720667157', ':heal:761252937548169246', ':dps:761252937066217512', '' ]
```

You should use

```
emojis=['<:tank:761252435720667157>', '<:heal:761252937548169246>', '<:dps:761252937066217512>', '' ]
```

This will solve your problem.
**EDIT**

When you use `if` statement, do `if str(emoji) == tank`, `if str(emoji) == heal`, `emoji` returns `discord.Reaction` class as I know. If you do this, it will work.

Comment: Hey :) Thanks for your reply :)

I tried with the <> like you said, but it's not working either :/ I edit the code above with the change

Comment: No, nothing happen when i press on the three custom emoji, and when i press the :slight_smile: it print "smiley" in the cmd prompt. Don't know how to debug it more :(

Comment: In the part of `else: return`, can you replace the `print(emoji)` with the `return`? So you can see what emoji you're getting.

Comment: smiley
<:dps:761252937066217512>
<:heal:761252937548169246>
<:tank:761252435720667157>

done

It print the good emoji i pressed

Comment: Was this all you wanted?

Comment: no :O it react with the else print (emoji), but not when i use :

if emoji == tank:
        print ("testtank")

this isn't working :(

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear... like i said i try to do it step by step, but at the end, when user press the tank emoji, it'll have to edit the embed with the name of the user

Comment: I edited the answer, look to the new part, it will work.